# Javascript/HTML based customisable shop items

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Lab4-Pizza.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function doSonic()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('sonicChecked').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('sonic').style.visibility="visible";

            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('sonic').style.visibility="hidden";
                cost=cost-1;
            }
    }

    function doDrake()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('drakeChecked').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('drake').style.visibility="visible";

            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('drake').style.visibility="hidden";
                cost=cost-2;
            }
    }

    function doEzio()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('ezioChecked').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('ezio').style.visibility="visible";

            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('ezio').style.visibility="hidden";
                cost=cost-1;
            }
    }

    function doJoel()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('joelChecked').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('joel').style.visibility="visible";

            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('joel').style.visibility="hidden";
                cost=cost-1;
            }
    }

    function doGta()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('gtaChecked').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('gta').style.visibility="visible";

            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('gta').style.visibility="hidden";
            }
    }

    function calcCost()
    {

        document.getElementById("costText").innerHTML = "The final cost of your pizza is:  €" + cost + ".00";
        alert("Please refresh page to create another pizza!");
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cost = 10.00;
    </script>



    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="images/redshirt.png" width="250" height="450"  alt="redshirt" id="redshirt" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
    </div>

    <img src="images/sonic.png" width="125" height="225"  alt="Sonic" id="sonic" style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 70px;"/>
    <img src="images/drake.png" width="150" height="250"  alt="drake" id="drake" style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 50px;" />
    <img src="images/Ezio.png" width="175" height="275" alt="ezio" id="ezio"style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 50px;" />
    <img src="images/joel.png" width="120" height="225"  alt="joel" id="joel"style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 60px;" />
    <img src="images/gta.png" width="150" height="250"  alt="gta" id="gta"style="position: absolute; top: 80px; left: 70px;" />
    </div>


    <input type="checkbox" id="sonicChecked" onclick="doSonic()" checked="true"> Sonic 
    <input type="checkbox" id="drakeChecked" onclick="doDrake()" checked="true"> Drake 
    <input type="checkbox" id="ezioChecked" onclick="doEzio()" checked="true"> Ezio
    <input type="checkbox" id="joelChecked" onclick="doJoel()" checked="true">  Joel 
    <input type="checkbox" id="gtaChecked" onclick="doGta()"checked="true" > GTA  

    <br><br>

    <div id="prices">
        <p><h2>Shirt Prices:</h2></p>
        <p>1. </p>
        <p>2. </p>
        <p>3. </p>
        <p>4. </p>
        <p>5.</p>
        <p>6.</p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="calcCost()">Done - Calculate Cost</button>
    <div id="costText" ></div>


 </body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering if someone can help me with this, I a making a website where a user can order a custom game character on a range of different coloured shirts. I am using layering to render a live mock up of the character on the coloured shirt.

The code above starts with all the character options on the shirt and they are removed with a check box. My question really is how do I only display the user selected character on the shirt while also making each option a unique order-able product that can be added to a cart.

Also currently it only does the red shirt how do I make the base image user selectable.

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: You may use `display` instead of `visibility`.

Comment: Not sure how you want your page to look.  I see the game character but where is the color selection?  Are you saying you want the user to start out with an empty cost total then select color and character?  Where is the pricing?  Why is cost static as 10?

Comment: I am currently adapting this from an earlier pizza example I haven't done the cost yet the price has to be displayed dynamically which is another issue for another day. I only have one shirt involved now yes I want an empty cost total and then to select the shirt colour and character.

Comment: Can you expand on the display instead of visibility idea please?